# Rectangle in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I try to draw a rectangle on a mfc window using the instructions by: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8w4fzfxf%28v=VS.80%29.aspx . Much though I tried, the Rectangle appears on the border of the window covering the whole of it. What is the problem with the following code int the function OnDraw(CDC* pDC) ? What can be done to draw a Rectangle with particular coordinates in the window?

```
 CPen penBlack;
 penBlack.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 0));
 CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&penBlack);

 CPoint pt(10, 10);
 CSize sz(100, 50);
 CRect myRect(pt, sz);
 GetClientRect(&myRect);

 pDC->Rectangle(&myRect);
```

Comment: Why do you call [`GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x(v=vs.80).aspx)? It would seem that this call overwrites your previously set-up coordinates in `myRect`.

Comment: You must be right, but it was suggested in the instructions.

Comment: You haven't copied the instructions exactly. You've just copied and pasted parts in random order. It retrieves the client rectangle, then shrinks it by 20 pixels in each direction, then draws *that* rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the call to `GetClientRect`.

That function will write to the rectangle object passed to it, so by calling, you're overwriting your specific coordinates that you set up just before the call using `pt` and `sz`.

Answer (score 1):

As @stakx suggested you should remove the `GetClientRect`, which gets the whole window client area, and overwrites your own rectangle.

As to the instruction, it first gets the whole client area, and shrinks the rectangle to get the rectangle to draw, so `GetClientRect` is needed there.

Answer (score 0):

This site will help you to draw the rectangle in mfc Dialog-based-application.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/37788-drawing-mfc.html

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/102490-cplusplus-mfc-rectangle-class.html

Don't use GetClientRect().It will override your previous coordinates.

Comment: This is not at all helpful. Answers are supposed to actually answer the question that was asked, not provide random links on the general subject.